# Do “break down” vs “break up” (meaning "to divide" something) have the same usage?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

According to the Cambridge dictionary (image below), the phrasal verbs ["break down"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/break-down) and ["break up"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/break-up) share the same meaning, "to divide something into smaller parts".

Moreover, according to [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/210827/142725) apparently there's a difference between these two phrasal verbs, but I'm not sure if that answer is correct.

Can someone explain if there is a difference between these two phrasal verbs?

[image: Break down meaning]
[image: Break up meaning]

Comment: I voted to close this because it seems to be a duplicate of the question that you linked to. If you're "not sure if that answer is correct", then you should provide a reason. Also, if you ask a new question, then it should be different from the earlier one. If you simply want clarification about the earlier question or answer, then you can comment on it, edit it, offer a bounty to encourage additional answers, etc.

Comment: @DialFrost not really, because the answer has no points, so I don't trust it.

Comment: @Marlonchosky  The answer was accepted (green tick) by the OP though. And there is another answer with 2 upvotes which strongly suggests it is a better answer. EDIT I now see that you posted a link to the actual upvoted answer. You need to add more detail and explain why that answer doesn't help.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The answer marked with the green tick had -1 votes yesterday, now it has +1 votes, and the other answer not marked with a green tick only provides an opinion, no external sources to give a foundation for his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The two expressions are synonymous and to some degree one can be exchanged with the other.

"Break down" includes the sense of create small manageable pieces.  In the example it takes about "breaking a task down".  Each piece is intended to be simpler than the whole.  It would be possible to have used "break up" in this sense.

"Break up" can have the sense of "smash" or "destroy" or "be destroyed".  So it is more suitable for the examples of the "ship breaking up".  These examples could not have been phrased with "break down"

And, both phrasal verbs also have other senses. "Break down" can also mean "decompose", or "cease to function", and "break up" can also mean "end a relationship".

Comment: But transitive _break up_ can be used both literally (physically breaking something apart) and metaphorically. I find transitive _break down_ odd for a physical process (though it's fine for a chemical one).

Comment: But in the example of break up our trip, it doesn't mean to destroy...

Comment: No, but has the sense of "split up" to make smaller, not to make simpler.